# Wordpress force 'view post' to open in a new tab after publish

Tags: wordpress, blog-post

My users are creating posts on the 'front'end' of wordpress, and are doing this within an custom styled iframe overlay.

After publishing the post, the standard message appears 'Post updated. View Post.'

Because the user is in an iframe overlay, clicking view post keeps them within the iframe and breaks the experience.

I'd like to force the 'view post' button in a new tab with _blank, but I assume this needs to be a function, I can't find a way to do it. Alternatively, hitting view post could close the iframe and go to the post.

Comment: "Because the user is in an iframe overlay" -- why is WP in an iframe?

Comment: It's in an iframe because we don't want the user to ever see the dashboard/admin area, and the upload new post functionality is best in our scenario to be done on the same page - see here for how we are doing it: [screenshot](http://imgur.com/N6i7hgL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links in iframe's work different, by default they will open in the iframe. You need to set the anchor's targets.

This will open it in the parent window:

```
target=_parent
```

This will open it in a new window/tab:

```
target=_blank
```

This will be some custom editing in your theme files. So if you're good with PHP and HTML, you wont have an issue!

Comment: Thanks @msbodetti - that could work. I'm ok with editing the theme, but the post-new template where this link presumably exists is not part of the theme, it's in the core files, so that is where I have come unstuck. Wondering if I can add a snipped to functions.php for this?

Comment: Yea creating hooks and filters for Wordpress Core Files is the way to go to get this sorted. I dont know if you created plugins before but that's what will need to be done. You can either create a new plugin or just add it in the functions.php file for your theme. You can read more about this here http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API